# Perl speed: difference between $a = $a.$b and $a .= $b

Tags: performance, perl, operations

I've put all the code and running info below. When handling very long strings, the speed of operations in the title is different. Why and How many other operations show the same characteristics?
(If the loops is lower than 10^4, the different is negligible.)

```
➜  ~  cat t1.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$a = 'a';

$i = 0;
while ($i < 100000){
  $a .= 'a';
  $i++;
}

➜  ~  time perl t1.pl
perl t1.pl  0.01s user 0.00s system 85% cpu 0.021 total



➜  ~  cat t2.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$a = 'a';

$i = 0;
while ($i < 100000){
  $a = $a.'a';
  $i++;
}

➜  ~  time perl t2.pl
perl t2.pl  0.50s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.507 total
```

Comment: Check `perl -MO=Concise -e '$a = $a.$b'` vs. `perl -MO=Concise -e '$a .= $b'`

Comment: I'm new to program. I guess this is something like Trace. I will try to learn this and then to understand the output. Thanks @Сухой27

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime is different because these are different operations:

> ```
> $a .= 'a';
> ```

This appends to `$a`. Strings in Perl have often room for more data at the end so in lots of cases this is just setting a single byte in the string and changing the length information.

> ```
> $a = $a.'a';
> ```

This creates a new string from `$a` and `'a'` and after this is done sets `$a` to this string. Thus first memory in at least the size of `$a` needs to be allocated and the content of `$a` need to be copied into this memory. Then the append is done, followed by the assignment and then the memory can be given back to Perl's internal memory management which depending on the OS and compile time options might give the memory back to the system.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you! So does this mean the same thing will not happen  for $a += 2 and $a = $a +2? Only for strings? @Steffen

Comment: @RodenLuo: These are still different actions (add vs. add and assign) so there will be a difference. But it will not be as noticeable as in the test with strings because there is far less memory allocation and copying there.

Comment: Oh, Okay, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Re "and after this is done sets $a to this string", This is actually quite efficient since it will simply transfer the string buffer from the temporary to `$a` rather than (enlarging and) copying. [Notice how the PV address changes even though no reallocation was needed in `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$a = "abcdef"; Dump($a); $a = substr($a, 0, -1) . "g"; Dump($a);'`] `$a = $a . $b` does indeed create a new scalar and requires copying `$a`, but only once (per loop pass).